# How to make next and previous button based on a menu

Tags: menus

I have left sidebar menu to navigate topics. Now I want to add next and previous button which actually refers to the menu' next and previous link respectively. i.e:
http://demo.voberhat.com/c-program/get-started/ this is my site and the next item of this link is: http://demo.voberhat.com/c-program/hello-world-c/. So when I am at http://demo.voberhat.com/c-program/get-started/, at the bottom I will see a link as next to refer: http://demo.voberhat.com/c-program/hello-world-c/ and same way a previous link will be displayed. I can add this manually but it is time consuming. Is there any plugin or trick to achieve this?